# Getting Kyocera TaskAlfa printer working with job accounting

Tags: printing

I'm working in an office that has a Kyocera TaskAlfa300i.  It has a job accounting system -- when I take a memory stick to it to print that way, I have to input my personal code, which charges the cost of paper to my project.  The PPD is [here](http://www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.co.uk/index/products/download_centre.false.driver.TASKALFA300I._.EN.html), which I installed via CUPS.

I can send jobs to the machine, but it throws an error that the job accounting code is wrong.  Colleagues with windows get a popup prompting for the code, but I don't.  Anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: Same problem. The only guide found is http://www.conewago.k12.pa.us/uploads/2/1/2/9/21299964/how_to_turn_on_kyocera_job_accounting.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by putting the job account ID in the printer manager. See picture below:

[image]

The manager was installed after installing the printer driver.